# jquery fullcalendar not rendering custom fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I added jquery full calendar and it works fine. But its not rendering custom fields properly.

```
$('.calendar').each(function () {
    var calendar = $(this);
    calendar.fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev, next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        editable: false,
        displayEventTime: false,
        eventLimit: true,
        events: [{"id":22,"title":"john","start":"2017-03-30","end":"2017-03-31","color":"green","allDay":true,"last_name":"doe"}],
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.attr("content",event.last_name)

        }

    });
})
```

Here the `last_name` is not showing in `calendar`. But default fields are showing fine. How can I show last_name in calendar?

Answer (score 1):

So this is the way to go if someone needs. Got this solution with some help from `github` issues.

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    element.append(event.last_name);
}
#or wrapping it with html:

eventRender: function(event, element) {
    element.append('<span style="color: pink;">' + event.last_name + '</span>');
}
```